# Change method for form generator in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using form generator for form create form in `Codeigniter`.

This form now using `POST` method, I want to change to `Get` method.

```php
<div class="col-md-10">
    <?php echo $form->open(); ?>
    <?php echo $form->messages(); ?>
    <?php echo $form->bs3_text('Insert Name', 'name'); ?>

    <div class="col-md-10" >
        <p><?php echo $form->bs3_submit('submit', 'btn btn-primary '); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->close(); ?>
</div>
```

Where to change method in this generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use below associative array and pass it to form_open()**

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'client', 'id' => 'myform', 'method' => 'get');
echo form_open('client/feedback', $attributes);
```

**output**

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/client/feedback"  class="client"  id="myform" method="get"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php echo $form->open('your_url','method="get"'); ?>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation.